# Navigation loop for a sequence of list items

Tags: jquery, loops, iteration

If you look at the top of the interface, I have 7 icons. Each icon has a corresponding label (using `<li>`) . When I click the 'Next' button, I want to show next label `<li>` and hide the previous one. I need this to happen in cycle so that once we reach the last `<li>` it loops.

I would obviously need the reverse of this for the back button.  My code so far:

```
$('#next2').click(function() {
    var nextItem = $('#labels li.select').hide().next('#labels li');
    if (nextItem.length === 0) {
        nextItem = $('#labels li').first();
    }

    nextItem.fadeIn().addClass('select');
    $('#labels li.select').prev().hide();
});

$('#prev2').click(function() {
    var prevItem = $('#labels li.select').hide().prev('#labels li');
    if (prevItem.length === 0) {
        prevItem = $('#labels li').last();
    }

    prevItem.fadeIn().addClass('select');
    $('#labels li.select').next().hide();
});
```

> HTML

```
<div style="margin-left:8%; margin-bottom:10px;">
    <ul id="labels">
        <li id="label-discover" class="select">Discover </li>
        <li id="label-collaborate">Collaborate </li>
        <li id="label-create">Create </li>
        <li id="label-develop">Develop </li>
        <li id="label-launch">Launch </li>
        <li id="label-maintain">Maintain </li>
        <li id="label-learn">Learn </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
#labels li {
    font-family: 'ArvoBold';
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    text-align:left;
    display:inline;
    display:none;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}

#labels li.deselect {
    display:none;
}

#labels li.select {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Why does the code you have not work for you? Could you also please post your HTML

Comment: Just use [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/), which has all that functionality and you can use the callbacks to change other parts of the page (like the menu).

Comment: I've already finished most of the coding and this is basically the only function that's left.

Comment: My 'Next' cycle is breaking for some reason and my 'Back' cycle is not going keeps going to the first element instead of the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're after, but I whipped this up quickly:

Preview: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/DYvRW/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var total= $('#labels').children().length - 1;
    var current = 0;

    $('#prev').click(function(e) {
        /* Stop page refreshing on anchor click */
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#labels').children().eq(current).hide();

        if(current === 0)
            current = total;
        else
            current--;

        $('#labels').children().eq(current).show();

    });

    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        /* Stop page refreshing on anchor click */
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#labels').children().eq(current).hide();

        if(current === total)
            current = 0;
        else
            current++;

        $('#labels').children().eq(current).show();

    });
});​​
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/abisom/2/edit)*

If you cave a counter initially set to '0' and you know the pages number:

```
var pagesN = 7 // or use: $('childrensOfSomeElement').length;
var c = 0;


 $('#prev, #next').click(function(){
    
    // logic //
    var myID = this.id=='next' ? c++ : c--;  
    c= c===-1? pagesN-1 : c%pagesN ;  
   
    console.log( c );

 });
```

after a click you can target **ANY** children element you want using the `.eq()` method